# Integrating Jenkins pipeline with keybase.io

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, keybase

My team is using keybase.io instead of slack, and I'd like our Jenkins results to post into the builds directory of our keybase team. So far I have a post step (I'm using a declarative pipeline) like so:

```
post {
    success {
        sh "echo 'Successful build of my app' | keybase chat send mycoolteam --channel builds"
    }
}
```

I also created a keybase account for our 'bot' and installed and logged in under the jenkins user on the build box. I can successfully send messages from the box to our keybase team using a similar

The error I'm seeing is like so:

```
keybase status
2018-05-05T07:53:41.578999Z ▶ [INFO keybase fork_server_nix.go:34] 001 Starting keybase.service.
Job for keybase.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl --user status keybase.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
2018-05-05T07:53:41.713575Z ▶ [ERRO keybase fork_server_nix.go:41] 002 Failed to start keybase.service.
2018-05-05T07:53:41.713609Z ▶ [ERRO keybase fork_server.go:54] 003 Error in spawning server process: exit status 1
2018-05-05T07:53:41.713695Z ▶ [ERRO keybase main.go:90] 004 exit status 1
```

Unfortunately, the systemctl and journalctl commands aren't giving me anything to work with. How can I ensure that jenkins can contact keybase via the pipeline script?

**Update:**

Tried using the -F flag with keybase after reading the suggestion [here.](https://github.com/keybase/client/issues/9094) Now the error looks like

```
 [ERRO keybase main.go:90] 001 dial unix /run/user/112/keybase/keybased.sock: connect: no such file or directory
```

Comment: I think you need to make a system-wide configuration for the keybase service to start during boot for the user you want - https://askubuntu.com/questions/676007/how-do-i-make-my-systemd-service-run-via-specific-user-and-start-on-boot